# How do I calculate the worst-case (theoretical) running time of this recursive function?

Tags: function, recursion, time, master-theorem

I am analyzing this block of code to review how to calculate the worst-case theoretical running time. I am using the Master Theorem. Could someone give me a step-by-step solution as to how to arrive at the running time?

```
def sort(list, i, j):
    if list[i] > list[j]:
        list[j], list[i] = list[i], list[j]
    if i + 1 >= j:
        return
    k = (j - i + 1)/3
    sort(list, i, j - k)
    sort(list, i + k, j)
    sort(list, i, j - k)
```

Comment: Do you need to call `sort(list, i, j - k)` twice?

Comment: Is this a 3-way quicksort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So master's theorem is `T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n)` where `a` is the amount of subproblems, `n/b` is the size of the subproblems, and `f(n)` is the amount of calculations you must due for every call.

`a:` There are three subproblems, or three recursive calls,

`n/b:` Each subproblem is fed at most `2/3` the original amount. You can prove it for each one, but to take an example: `sort(list, i, j-k)` has a problem size from `(j-k) - i`, which is `j-(j-i+1)/3 - i = (2j - 2i - 1)/3`

`f(n):` is `O(1)`, or bounded by constant time, since you're just doing two constant time switches.

This should come about to `O(n^(log(3) base (2/3)))` Sorry about the math notation, I'm not sure how to use it on stack overflow.